# Erro na instalação do EntityFramework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core

Estou começando uma aplicação em angular com ASP.Net, e no video que estou vendo, o instrutor diz que instalemos Microsoft.EntityFramework pelo NuGet, porem estou tendo esse erro:

```
 Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error    
NETSDK1045 The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.  
Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that 
supports .NET Core 2.2. WebAPI
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.505\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 137
```

Porem a versão instala do meu .NET já é a 2.2

Comment: Qual a versão do Entity Framework que está tentando instalar ? As vezes a versão é incompatível com a versão do Core que está instalado, que aparentemente é a mensagem que está sendo apresentada para você.

Comment: Felippe, tendei quase todas (inclusive a 1.0.0)! Troquei ate a SDK do .NET

Comment: Tente ir em Ferramentas -> Opções Projetos e Soluções -> .NET Core e marcar a opção Usar as versões prévias do SDK do .NET Core

Comment: @RavelSbrissaOkada Qual .NET você está usando?

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 SDK - (v2.2.203)

Comment: Felippe, continuou com o mesmo erro!

Comment: @RavelSbrissaOkada você tentou fazer o que eu havia escrito no meu último comentário ?

Comment: Sim @FelippeTadeu

Comment: Digite `dotnet --info` no console e veja qual a versão que está sendo apresentada

Comment: 2.2.203 
Aproveitando o gancho, o fato da SDK estar instalada no SSD e o Visual Studio code no HD pode estar interfirindo? Lembrei disso agora

Comment: Faça um arquivo global.json e nele aponte o sdk que será utilizado

Comment: Usando o comentário do @LucasMiranda, pode ser que a versão também esteja apontando para a errada

Comment: @LucasMiranda poderia me instruir melhor de como fazer isso, sou realmente novato nessa area

Comment: Segue link com todo o procedimento https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/global-json

Comment: O erro persiste, vou para a faculdade agora então é possivel que pare de dar retorno as soluções. Agradeço mesmo assim.

Comment: Amigo, no core você precisa instalar o Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore e não o Microsoft.EntityFramework, remova e instale o package certo: Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 2.2.4

Comment: Amigos, o problema foi resolvido, voltei minha SDK uma versão e funcionou